# Duplicate geopoint detection

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm trying to figure out if it is possible write an ElasticSearch query that will filter the results to only include documents with a geopoint that is within a certain distance from another arbitrary document's geopoint.

Edit:

Here is the SQL equivalent of what I am trying to do.

```sql
SELECT "a".*
FROM "documents" as "a" 
WHERE EXISTS(
  SELECT 1 
  FROM "documents" as "b" 
  WHERE "a"."id" != "b"."id" 
  AND st_distance("a"."point","b"."point) < 100
  LIMIT 1
);
```

Comment: It's always easier to help if you can provide a small example

Comment: @Val I added a sql equivalent example of what I am trying to do but I don't know how to write it in elasticsearch query syntax.